# GridView - open image in new activity

Tags: android, gridview, textview, imageview

Currently my project has a GridView that has images and a description under each one. On click on an image it should open in a new activity with the full image and description under it.

It is currently working fine on emulator, but the onclick does nothing on real device.

If I change `intent.putExtra("image", item.getImage())` to `intent.putExtra("image", bitmap)` in MainActivity, it opens the new, secondary DetailsActivity, but only shows the text and not the image. Logcat doesn't show errors for this change, only says that "java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable".

MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    gridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_item_layout, getData());
    gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

            ImageItem item = (ImageItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("title", item.getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("image", item.getImage());

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}


private ArrayList<ImageItem> getData() {
    final ArrayList imageItems = new ArrayList();
    String[] itemsArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.grid_ids);

    TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.image_ids);
    for (int i = 0; i < imgs.length(); i++) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), imgs.getResourceId(i, -1));
        imageItems.add(new ImageItem(bitmap, itemsArray[i]));
    }
    return imageItems;
}
```

DetailsActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    String title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
    Bitmap image = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("image");

    TextView titleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    titleTextView.setText(title);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
```

ImageItem class:

```
public class ImageItem {

public Bitmap image;
public String title;

public ImageItem(Bitmap image, String title) {
    super();
    this.image = image;
    this.title = title;
}

public Bitmap getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(Bitmap image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
```

GridViewAdapter:

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ImageItem> {

private Context context;
private int layoutResourceId;
private ImageView imageView;
private ArrayList<ImageItem> data = new ArrayList<ImageItem>();

public GridViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<ImageItem> data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imageTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text);
        holder.image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image);

        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    ImageItem item = data.get(position);
    holder.imageTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
    holder.image.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());
    return row;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView imageTitle;
    ImageView image;
}
```

The images (in R.drawable) and descriptions are listed in the strings.xml in two string arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the bitmap might be too large for encode & decode or pass as a byte array in the intent. This can cause either OOM or a bad UI experience.

As you are only using drawable files ,instead of bitmap you can use int value in your model class:

you can add your drawable id in your model class as below:

imageItems.add(new ImageItem(imgs.getResourceId(0, -1), itemsArray[i]));

While using it in adapter :

holder.image.setImageResource(imgs.getResourceId(0, -1));

you can send this int to your detail activity and over there you can set:

int imageId = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("image"); imageView.setImageResource(imageId);

**Updated Answer**

Your Model Class:

public class ImageItem {

// Instead of bitmap use int public int image; public String title;

public ImageItem(int image, String title) { // here it will go your resource id this.image = image; this.title = title; }

public int getImage() { return image; }

public void setImage(int image) { this.image = image; }

public String getTitle() { return title; }

public void setTitle(String title) { this.title = title; }

}

**In your MainActivity:**

gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {

```
    ImageItem item = (ImageItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("title", item.getTitle());
        intent.putExtra("image", item.getImage());

    startActivity(intent);
}
});
```

private ArrayList getData() { final ArrayList imageItems = new ArrayList(); String[] itemsArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.grid_ids);

```
TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.image_ids);
for (int i = 0; i < imgs.length(); i++) {
imageItems.add(new ImageItem(imgs.getResourceId(0, -1), itemsArray[i]));
}
return imageItems;
```

}

**In your DetailsActivity:**

@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

String title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
int image = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("image");

TextView titleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
titleTextView.setText(title);

ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
imageView.setImageResource(image);
```

**In your adater:**

holder.image.setImageResource(imgs.getResourceId(0, -1));

Comment: I've tried adding the first suggested line of code but it gives me options to 'change 1st parameter of method 'ImageItem' from 'Bitmap' to 'Int' OR to 'Create a Constructor' - If I create a constructor it creates it in ImageItem.java  ( public ImageItem(int resourceId, String title) { }  ) . Do I need to write in the resourceId and the String title? When copying the 2nd line of code to GridViewAdapter, imgs becomes red, options-create local variable 'imgs', create field 'imgs', create parameter 'images' or rename reference?

Comment: 3rd line of code, imageView becomes red, options are create local variable, bring ImageView image view into scope, create field, create parameter, rename reference. I'm a novice in programming and and don't really know how to apply this correctly yet. I'm still getting a code that doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I have replied on the comment by posting the updated answer after the previous answer. It is posted under the title "Updated Answer". Please check the answer and let me know is it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

to make your implementation more easier you can have that image model object to have an image resource id through the constructor as following.

```
public class ImageItem {

public int image;
public String title;

public ImageItem(int image, String title) {
    // image means your image resource id
    this.image = image;
    this.title = title;
}

public int getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(int image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

}
```

in your onClick method you can do so like below

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

    ImageItem item = (ImageItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("title", item.getTitle());
        // your image resource should be int
        intent.putExtra("imageId", item.getImage());

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

your DetailsActivity will do the following...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    String title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");

    // here -1 is the default value for, if that extra isn't found
    int image = getIntent().getIntExtra("imageId", -1);

    TextView titleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    titleTextView.setText(title);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    imageView.setImageResource(image);
```